# Conjugate of Bessel functions of purely imaginary order

Tags: complex-analysis, special-functions

I would like to find a relation between $J_{i\nu}(x)$ and $J^*_{i\nu}(x)$ where $J$ are Bessel functions of the first kind, $*$ denotes the conjugate, and $\nu,x\in \mathbb{R}$ so that the functions have a purely imaginary order.

My intuition is that $J^*_{i\nu}(z)=J_{-i\nu}(z^*)$ if $z\in\mathbb{C}$ so in my case I will have $J^*_{i\nu}(x)=J_{-i\nu}(x)$ but I haven't found any proof for this result.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I would use a integral representation of $J_\alpha$: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function#Bessel's_integrals

Comment: Thank you, I think the second expression is the one I need to prove my conjecture.